# How to keep rows in categorical data?

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a data set for an animal shelter, where the parameter "breed" has over 50 different possibilities. I looked at the summary of the data and there are 4 breeds that dominate the parameter. My question is, how do I make a data set that only includes those four breeds (and keeps all other parameters the same)?

Here's what I tried so far: (`meow2` is the original data)

```
meow3 <- meow2[ which(meow2$breed1=="domestic shorthair" & "domestic mediumhair" & "domestic longhair" & "siamese"),]
```

Some online research suggested that I create a subset? here was my attempt:

```
meow3 <- subset(meow2, breed1=="domestic shorthair" "domestic meduimhair" "domestic longhair" "siamese")
```

I am sure there is some formatting issues, but I'm really having a hard time finding online resources for this. I've tried investigating the errors as well, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: I think that you want `meow3 <- meow2[meow2$breed1 %in% c("domestic shorthair", "domestic mediumhair", "domestic longhair", "siamese"),]`

Comment: @Hunaidkhan, that won't work either (you need `%in%`, not `==`)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is with `%in%`:

```
common_breeds <- c("domestic shorthair","domestic mediumhair",
          "domestic longhair", "siamese")   
meow3 <- subset(meow2, breed1 %in% common_breeds)
```

You *could* do something like

```
 ... breed1=="domestic shorthair" | breed1=="domestic mediumhair" |
     breed1=="domestic longhair" | breed1=="siamese" ...
```

(you need to use `|` (or) rather than `&` (and) ...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use dplyr and forcats , in this example I set the limit to 1 factor, change for your data as needed

```
library(tidyverse)



testing <- data.frame(factors = factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,3)))


testing %>% 
  mutate(factors = factors %>% fct_lump_n(n = 1,other_level = "other")) %>% 
  filter(factors != "other")
```

If you need a specific list frozen in time use the fct_other function instead

```
testing2 <-
  data.frame(factors = factor(
    c(
      "domestic shorthair",
      "domestic mediumhair",
      "domestic longhair",
      "siamese"
    )
  ))

testing2 %>% 
  mutate(factors = factors %>% fct_other(keep = c("domestic shorthair","domestic mediumhair"),other_level = "other")) %>%
  filter(factors != "other")
```